Generalized Rademacher theorem for fractional derivatives
It is known that if $f$ is $\alpha$ Holder and $\gamma<\alpha$ then $f$ is $\gamma$ fractional differentiable. See Theorem 14 in the paper by G. H. Hardy and J. E. Littlewood, "Some properties of fractional integrals. I."
Mathematische Zeitschrift 27, 565-606 (1928), JFM 54.0275.05.
Rademacher's theorem says that if $f$ is $1$ Holder then $f$ is $1$ differentiable almost everywhere.

Suppose that $f$ is $\alpha$ Holder. Is $f$ $\alpha$ differentiable almost everywhere?

Recall that
$$D^\alpha f(x):=\frac{1}{\Gamma(1-\alpha)}\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^x\frac{f(t)}{(x-t)^\alpha}dt.$$

I presume that by fractional differentiability, you specifically refer to it in the context of the Riemann-Liouville differential operator? (As opposed to, say, the Caputo fractional derivative)

@MaxMuller yes, wrt the operator I wrote. Thanks.
